# Can the "c" statement be used along with the "which" statement?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am interested in seeing whether the "c" statement can be used along with the "which" statement in R. For example, consider the following code (var1 and var2 are both "Factor" variables):

```
 my_file

  var1 var2
1    A   AA
2    B   CC
3    D   CC
4    C   AA
5    A   BB

ouput <- my_file[which(my_file$var1 == c("A", "B", "C") & my_file$var2 !== c("AA", "CC")), ]
```

But this does not seem to be working.

I can run each of these conditions individually, e.g.

```
output <- my_file[which(my_file$var1 == "A" | my_file$var1 == "B" | my_file$var1 == "C"), ]
output1 <- output[which(output$var2 == "AA" | output$var2 == "CC" ), ]
```

But I would like to run them in a more "compact" form, e.g.:

```
ouput <- my_file[which(my_file$var1 == c("A", "B", "C") & my_file$var2 !== c("AA", "CC")), ]
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`. An maybe easier way would be to use the `filter` function from `dplyr` instead of the long `which…`.

Comment: Beware of `NA`'s though, since e.g. `NA %in% "A"` gives `FALSE` and not `NA`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare `my_file$var1 == c("A", "B", "C")`, the comparison will take place element-by-element, but because they are different lengths, the shorter will be repeated (with a warning because the repeating is incomplete.
`c("A", "B", "D", "C", "A") == c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B")` giving:
`c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`, then `which` will convert to `c(1, 2)`.
The reason it works when you use one letter at a time is that the single element is repeated 5 times `my_file$var1 == "A"` leads to `c("A", "B", "D", "C", "A") == c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A")` and gives the result you expect.

@deschen is right, you should use %in%
`output <- my_file[which(my_file$var1 %in% c("A", "B", "C") & !my_file$var2 %in% c("AA", "CC")), ]`

Answer (score 1):

As @deschen says in a comment, you should use `%in%` rather than `==`. You can also (1) get rid of the `which()` (logical indexing works just as well here as indexing by position) and (2) use `subset` to avoid re-typing `my_file`.

```r
output <- subset(my_file, var1 %in% c("A", "B", "C") & 
                         !(var2 %in% c("AA", "CC")))
```

Alternatively, if you like the tidyverse, this would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
output <- my_file %>% dplyr::filter(var1 %in% c("A", "B", "C"),
                           !(var2 %in% c("AA", "CC")))
```

(comma-separated conditions in `filter()` work the same as `&`).